# Angular 2 APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have been searching google for the last day and I have a fundamental question about APP_INITIALIZER in angular 2. Documentation on the official site does not clear this out.

APP_INITIALIZER can be used only on RootModule or on any other custom module as well?

I have several lazy load modules and each one has its own configuration. I want to load configuration for a lazy load module before that module loads.
More specific I am using a 3rd party lib that exposes a service (Service A). This service has ConfigA injected into its constructor. I fetch the config from my server using http and I want to map it as ConfigA which will be injected into ServiceA.

Comment: _I want to load configuration for a lazy load module before that module loads._ - and use how?

Comment: can you put some pseudocode in the question?

Comment: @Maximus the 3rd party library is https://github.com/stomp-js/ng2-stompjs
Check the StompService it accepts a StompConfig object. As I explained I have several lazy load modules. Each module has its own StompService thus its own StompConfig. In order for a module to start a StompService has to be initialized.

LazyModule1 has a componentA
ComponentA has StompService injected in its constructor

Comment: do you define both `StompConfig` and `StompService` as providers on a lazy module?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @pantonis this is my problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56881501/initializer-like-app-initializer-in-lazy-loaded-modules

Answer (score 0):

> APP_INITIALIZER can be used only on RootModule or on any other custom
>   module as well?

Since `APP_INITIALIZER` is just a provider, you can register it on any module that is not lazy-loaded.

Read more [here](https://hackernoon.com/hooking-into-the-angular-bootstrap-process-36e82a01fba8)

Comment: What about lazy loaded modules. Is there any way to have similar behavior? e.g load config for a module before anything else loads

Comment: lazy loaded modyles are loaded when the applicaion is already initialized

Comment: Resolver can help here https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/10/resolving-route-data-in-angular-2.html

Comment: @yurzui Resolver can only be used for routing data?

/**
 * whatItDoes Represents the resolved data associated with a particular route.
 * See {@link Routes} for more details.
 * stable
 */
export declare type ResolveData = {
    [name: string]: any;
};

Comment: @pantonis, what are you trying to do? why do you need `APP_INITIALIZER `?

Comment: I have several lazy load modules and each one has its own configuration. I want to load configuration for a lazy load module before that module loads.

Comment: what do you mean by _load_ configuration? can you put it inside module's class constructor?

Comment: I am using a 3rd party lib that exposes a service (Service A). This service has ConfigA injected into its constructor. I fetch the config from my server using http and I want to map it as ConfigA which will be injected into ServiceA

Comment: @pantonis, well, add these details to the question with some examples, at the moment your question is misleading

Comment: @Maximus thanks just did. Do you know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As @yurzui mentioned:
In lazy module create route path definition with resolver.
In this resolver class implement the resolve function. The resolve function can return Promise object and this helps you to implement the initialization logic.

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalizationResolve implements Resolve<any> {

  constructor(
    public localizationConfig: LocalizationConfig) {
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return this.localizationConfig.load();
  }
}
```

Route defintion:

```
 path: '', component: SecureComponent, resolve: { locale: LocalizationResolve }
```