# MODULE_INITIALIZER like APP_INITIALIZER in lazy loaded modules

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-services

**Does any one know any functionality like APP_INITIALIZER that we can use in our lazy loaded modules?**

> Any workaround appreciated!!!

- I need to perform some API calls before module gets initialized and
  it will return a promise.
- Calling from constructor not appreciated.
- Using resolve in app-routing-module not appreciated.

Comment: I would go with Resolvers.

Comment: I had enough complexity in routing module that's why I am not appreciating resolvers.So, I had to get my configration data in my lazy loaded module before module gets initialiazed.Is there any other way around? @pantonis